# How do you custom format the textfield?

Tags: iphone, xcode, textfield

I know NSNumberFormatter allows you some flexibility in customising the textfield but if you need a more specific formatter, how you would do it please?

For example:

Timecode "03:50:02:25"?

or

Concatenation of strings "6,264 feet"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:) but it more useful in filtering the input or formatting the input after the text has been entered.